# fix consult, the records are duplicated

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running a query to search all products that are not related to a table called Stock .The field "Ruta" inside the Stock table is different from the id found in the Url. I am doing it in the following way:

```
 @productos = Producto.joins('left outer join stock on productos.Clave=stock.Articulo').select('productos.*,stock.Articulo').where('stock.ruta != ? AND productos.Status = ?', params[:id], "A")
```

The problem with this query is that it is showing me the repeated products, depending on the quantity of stocks to which the product is associated, how could I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `distinct`:

`@productos = Producto.joins('left outer join stock on productos.Clave=stock.Articulo').select('productos.*,stock.Articulo').where('stock.ruta != ? AND productos.Status = ?', params[:id], "A").distinct`

or you can add `group('productos.Clave')`

Comment: It works but I have a small problem, I am searching these records by "ruta" with the param id, when de product is related to  another Stock with a different "ruta" And the "ruta" that I am going through parameter already has related that article, the query keeps bringing me the same article, but the stock with "ruta" id params already has the article, how can I solve this?

Comment: @LuisC Sorry, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: if the product is related to Stock with the "Ruta"(this is a fiel in stock) equal to the id that I am sending through the url, the query should not show the product, but if this product also is related to another Stock with different "Ruta" The query shows me the product, but should not. Here I put my  question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687403/search-records-by-query-consult

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like

```
Stock.includes(:products).where(products: { stock_id: nil })
```